# IDE for Sencha Touch

Tags: ide, eclipse-plugin, extjs, javascript

I'm new to Sencha touch 2. Is there any Sencha touch IDE(free one)? Basically what I want is when I write something like .. new Ext and just give space+cntrl so there should be list of all the methods and properties of it. 
OR
is there any way through which I can add sencha touch javascript libraries in eclipse ? Like we do with Komodo Editor. In komodo Editor you just need to add the javascript library and it will automatically fetch all the functions,methods,and properties that resides in that library file.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: As of now there is no such type of Procedure possible with sencha touch.if you want to check the methods and possible properties just refer this link http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api

Comment: Go with Aptana, you can configure it to support any JS libraries for auto-complete etc.

Comment: I have created a detailed tutorial with pictures for this specific reason, Please let me know what do you think and how it worked out :) http://www.shereef.net/2012/12/11/sencha-touch-2-autocomplete-example-in-aptana-studio/

Answer (score 7):

Before we start please download the following files:

1. sencha-touch-2.0.0-gpl.zip or sencha-touch-2.0.0-commercial.zip
2. SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3
3. Aptana Studio 3
4. Extract sencha-touch-2.0.0-(gpl.zip/commercial.zip) to a place of
   your liking (Note it will stay there for a long time)
5. SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3 and/or install it
6. open up the terminal or command prompt
7. cd into the folder of Sencha Touch SDK
   (sencha-touch-2.0.0-(gpl/commercial)
8. write: sencha generate app APP_NAME APP_PATH
9. hit enter (return)
10. extract/install Aptana studio
11. Open up Aptana studio
12. Click the help menu
13. Choose Install New Software
14. A window will open click Add
15. Name it Spket IDE then enter the url http://www.agpad.com/update
16. Press OK
17. Choose everything then click Next
18. Click next
19. Read the license ( like everyone does, NOT!), and then accept if
     you want, then press next
20. Wait for the install to complete (Restart if required)
21. Go to Preferences
22. Navigate to Spket then JavaScript Profiles
23. Click Add
24. Type Sencha
25. Press Ok
26. Highlight Sencha
27. Click Add Library, Select ExtJs
28. Highlight ExtJs then click Add file
29. Choose touch.jsb3 from the folder you extracted the Sencha Touch
     SDK 2.0.0 in
30. Select all items in the tree
31. Highlight Sencha then click default
32. Press ok
33. File > New > Other > General > Project
34. uncheck the box that says to use the default location
35. Browse to the project you created earlier
36. Type the name of the project (preferably exactly the same name as
     it’s folder)
37. Press finish
38. expand the view folder and open the Main.js
39. type Ext. if the auto complete doesn’t pop up type crtl + space

I have created a detailed [tutorial](http://www.shereef.net/2012/12/11/sencha-touch-2-autocomplete-example-in-aptana-studio/) with pictures for this specific reason, Please let me know what do you think and how it worked out :)

Comment: how to run the application imported into eclipse

Comment: Same way you run it out of eclipse, go to http://localhost/....

Answer (score 3):

I use Netbeans (http://netbeans.org) it's free, but doesn't have the methods you want to auto complete & use, the best for that I found to be Aptana studio (http:www.aptana.com) but that is paid.

For netbeans you can modify the IDE so it does auto complete based on the libraries in Sencha :-

a) Right click on the SenchaApp application and select Properties from the drop down menu

b) Under the Libraries menu, choose “Add Libraries” and from the window that opens click “Create…”

c) Name the Library “Sencha_Touch” and choose “Class Library” from the drop down.

d) Under the “Classpath” tab, click on “Add JAR/Folder” and select the “touch” folder previously downloaded.

e) Click “OK” and choose the newly created “Sencha_Touch” library.

To check if you’ve added code completion correctly, create an app.js file in the app folder. Type Ext followed by a “.” — If the steps above were followed correctly, the code completion should work.

Or move over at http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/using-netbeans-ide-with-sencha-touch/

Answer (score 2):

- TextMate with bundles from Ed Spencer: http://edspencer.net/tag/textmate

  - Sublime Text 2, I think you can use same bundles as for TextMate, not sure!
  - JetBrainsWebStorm3 is used by many
  - Aptana (eclipse based), there is a plugin for Sencha, but not touch I think.

But I think you might enjoy Sencha Designer 2: http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-designer-2-beta-announcement/

As Nag said: make use of the API's.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Pocket Dev

http://www.pocketdev.co/blog/sencha

It's pretty basic but works well

Answer (score 2):

Try Sublime Text 2. It is the best i came across.
You can download it from this link by selecting your OS: http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Answer (score 1):

Aptana Studio 3 is the best for Sencha 1.1 or Sencha 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sencha architect???

http://www.sencha.com/products/architect

Comment: yes you can only try it, unless you pay

Comment: no evaluation trial is free for 30 days

Answer (score 1):

+1 on JetBrains WebStorm 3 .. it has built in helpers/popups that know the Sencha language. And the way it auto-formats for you (when pressing return or pasting in code) is very intuitive to JS and helpful for the user. Just my to pennies.